# Facebook App - Cannot click cancel on app details page

Tags: facebook

We have created a Facebook application in the dashboard of https://developers.facebook.com when we click on the app details link we get the notice as below:

"Editing App Info is disabled because your App Details submission is pending review. To make changes, you may cancel your pending submission."

Cancel is a hyperlink however it does not work. We need to essentially cancel the pending app submission in order to make relevant changes to the app, short description, tagline etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the **Status & Review** tab  and there you'll find the option to cancel the submission.

Comment: I have the same problem, and there is nothing listed under: "Status & Review" - no submissions.

Comment: I am getting the same issue, but I don't have anything showing on the status page either.  All we did was to change the url from a test url that was approved, to the production url, so we could open it up to users.  Not sure what to do next...